# Purescript Reuse Argonaut JSON Decoding for Affjax Respondeable

Tags: purescript, argonaut

I'm trying to fetch some JSON data from a Haskell server, but I'm having trouble with the Respondeable instance, as well as just Affjax in general. I've defined EncodeJson + DecodeJson with Data.Argonaut.Generic.Aeson (GA), but I can't figure out how to fit that in with the Respondeable instance and it's fromResponse function.

It gives me the error "Could not match type Foreign with type Json" but is it possible to reuse my decodeJson instance without having to create anything else by hand? Maybe by creating an IsForeign instance, but using GA.decodeJson in that? I'm just not sure how to go about doing it. I've seen how it's done in https://github.com/purescript/purescript-foreign/blob/master/examples/Complex.purs by hand, but I have complex types that need to match up with my Haskell JSON output, and it's going to be a huge pain to do it manually.

I'm using purescript 10.7, Affjax 3.02, and argonaut 2.0.0, and argonaut-generic-codecs 5.1.0. Thanks!

```
testAffjax :: forall eff. Aff (ajax :: AJAX | eff) (Answer)
testAffjax = launchAff do
  res <- affjax $ defaultRequest { url = "/", method = Left GET }
  pure res.response


data Answer = Answer {
  _answer :: String
, _isCorrect :: Boolean
, _hint :: String
}

{- PROBLEM -}
instance respondableAnswer :: Respondable Answer where
  responseType = Tuple Nothing JSONResponse
  fromResponse = GA.decodeJson {- Error here -}

derive instance genericAnswer :: Generic Answer
instance showAnswer :: Show Answer where
  show = gShow
instance encodeAnswer :: EncodeJson Answer where
  encodeJson = GA.encodeJson
instance decodeAnswer :: DecodeJson Answer where
  decodeJson = GA.decodeJson
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you're looking for is a function that adapts a JSON decoder:

```
decodeJson :: forall a. Json -> Either String a
```

To return using `F` rather than `Either`. `F` is a synonym defined in `Data.Foreign` for `Except MultipleErrors a`. To do that we need to:

1. Translate our `String` error into a `MultipleErrors`
2. Convert from `Either` to `Except`

`MultipleErrors` is another synonym defined in `Data.Foreign`, this time for `NonEmptyList ForeignError`. [Looking at `ForeignError`](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-foreign/3.2.0/docs/Data.Foreign#t:ForeignError) there's a constructor also called `ForeignError` that lets us provide some string message. That leaves us with the need to create a `NonEmptyList`, which is pretty easy:

```
remapError = pure <<< ForeignError
```

`NonEmptyList` is `Applicative`, so we can create a one-element list with `pure`.

To go from `Either` to `Except` is also straightforward. Again [looking at the definitions in Pursuit](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-transformers/2.3.0/docs/Control.Monad.Except) we can see:

```
newtype ExceptT m e a = ExceptT (m (Either e a))
type Except = ExceptT Identity
```

So `ExceptT` is just a fancy `Either` already, giving us:

```
eitherToExcept = ExceptT <<< pure
```

The `pure` here is to lift `Either e a` into `m (Either e a)`, which for `Except` `m ~ Identity`.

So now we can take this stuff, and make a general "decode JSON for Affjax responses" function:

```
decodeJsonResponse :: forall a. DecodeJson a => Json -> F a
decodeJsonResponse =
  ExceptT <<< pure <<< lmap (pure <<< ForeignError) <<< decodeJson
```

The only other thing that happened in here is we used `lmap` to map over the left part of the `Either`, to do the error-message-type-conversion bit.

We can now use Kleisli composition ([`(<=<)`](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-prelude/2.4.0/docs/Control.Bind#v:(%3C=%3C))) to chain this `decodeJsonResponse` together with the original `fromResponse` that will do the initial `ResponseContent -> F Json`:

```
instance respondableAnswer :: Respondable Answer where
  responseType = Tuple (Just applicationJSON) JSONResponse
  fromResponse = decodeJsonResponse <=< fromResponse
```

Here's the full example using your `Answer` type:

```
module Main where

import Prelude

import Control.Monad.Aff (Aff)
import Control.Monad.Except (ExceptT(..))

import Data.Argonaut (class DecodeJson, class EncodeJson, Json, decodeJson)
import Data.Argonaut.Generic.Argonaut as GA
import Data.Bifunctor (lmap)
import Data.Foreign (F, ForeignError(..))
import Data.Generic (class Generic, gShow)
import Data.Maybe (Maybe(..))
import Data.MediaType.Common as MediaType
import Data.Tuple (Tuple(..))

import Network.HTTP.Affjax as AX
import Network.HTTP.Affjax.Response as AXR

testAffjax :: forall eff. Aff (ajax :: AX.AJAX | eff) Answer
testAffjax = _.response <$> AX.get "/"

newtype Answer = Answer
  { _answer :: String
  , _isCorrect :: Boolean
  , _hint :: String
  }

derive instance genericAnswer :: Generic Answer

instance showAnswer :: Show Answer where
  show = gShow

instance encodeAnswer :: EncodeJson Answer where
  encodeJson = GA.encodeJson

instance decodeAnswer :: DecodeJson Answer where
  decodeJson = GA.decodeJson

instance respondableAnswer :: AXR.Respondable Answer where
  responseType = Tuple (Just MediaType.applicationJSON) AXR.JSONResponse
  fromResponse = decodeJsonResponse <=< AXR.fromResponse

decodeJsonResponse :: forall a. DecodeJson a => Json -> F a
decodeJsonResponse =
  ExceptT <<< pure <<< lmap (pure <<< ForeignError) <<< decodeJson
```

Comment: That's terrifying. It's going to take me some more time to figure out what's going on here, but it works. Thanks!

Comment: It would be nice to have this as a library. Thanks!